# How to turn off dimming of inactive editor panes in Brackets editor? [Image included]

Tags: editor, text-editor, adobe-brackets

How can I turn off the active windown hight light, so that both side of the window look the same. The grey deactive highlight is really hard to look through. **What I want is that both sides look like the right side in the image provided.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimming of inactive editor panes was disabled in the latest (1.2) version of Brackets.

That degree of brightness difference is pretty extreme, though. You might have an extension installed whose CSS is messing up the appearance. Try *Debug > Reload Without Extensions* to check, and make sure you don't have the "Zen Panes" extension installed (it does the same thing as the built-in dimming, so it might be doubling the effect).